# How can I reformat JavaScript code in WebStorm?

Tags: node.js, ide, webstorm

I am using JetBrains WebStorm IDE. But I think there is not shortcut to autoformat (beautify) the code. In Netbeans, its <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> command which formats the whole file. Is there any command for this? Do I need to install any plugin or something to enable this function?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

`Code` | `Reformat Code...` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>):

[image]

Keyboard shortcut can be changed in `File` | `Settings` | `Keymap`:

[image]

If you are not familiar with IDE features yet, use `Help` | `Find Action`:

[image]

This [feature is also documented](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/reformatting-source-code.html).

Comment: Thanks. In WebStorm 8 formatting content changed to Alt+F8.

Answer (score 10):

Yes.

Opt+Cmd+L (Mac, or whatever your platform combo is)

Or Code > Reformat Code...

Answer (score 1):

Using WebStorm 8.0.4 in Windows the hotkey is (has become?) Alt-F8.

Comment: what about Mac?