# WebStorm: reformat tab width on existing files

Tags: webstorm

I'm trying out WebStorm and I've run into a minor, but frustrating problem: working from an existing project, files open with their tab width set to 2 instead of 4.

In `Settings -> Code Style -> JavaScript` I have `use tab character` selected and the `tab size/indent/continuation indent` all set to 4, but <kbd>Ctrl + Alt + I</kbd> [from here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.1/changing-indentation.html) which should 'fix' the indentation from 2 to 4 doesn't do anything, nor does `Code -> Reformat Code` as per this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15851023/how-can-i-reformat-js-code-in-webstorm)

Ultimately, I just want all tabs to be interpreted as a 4 space tab instead of a 2 space tab project-wide (css, scss, javascript, html).

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Do you have any `.editorconfig` files in this project? Settings from such file(s) will overwrite your Code Style settings (that's the point/purpose of such files).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37632620/783119